# What to do if you're still praying but the congregation began reciting psalms for the state of Israel?

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, tefillah-betzibbur

If I have not yet finished praying but the congregations has - if the hazzan began reciting psalms for the safety in the state of israel, do you interrupt your prayers and join in with the congregation or do you finish your prayers and then say what you can with the congregation or by yourself?

Comment: Are Ketoret and Shir Shel Yom a prayer? What for?

Comment: @DoubleAA, would you consider *Aleynu* a prayer? (Note that when I say prayer I am referring to the entire seder of tefilos,  tehillim, etc. said during shachrit.)

Comment: In your sense of the word 'prayer' then sure, though why you'd use that definition is unclear. All traditional prayer services end with Kaddish Shalem. Many are accustomed to say or do certain things in conjunction with prayer services, probably as a good time to remember to say/do them.

Comment: @DoubleAA by your definition, Why is Pesukei Dezimra a prayer? Its just praising god! (Just like shir shel yom , most of it even has the same source and writer - David Hamelech!)

Comment: @SamuelManuel Traditional prayer begins with praise and moves to requests and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ketoret and Shir Shel Yom do not seem to be requests. Additionally they do not need a minyan to say them.

The [Gemoro Brochos 8a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=8&format=text) indicates that Hashem does not despise the prayers (requests) of the many.

> רבי נתן אומר מנין שאין הקב"ה מואס בתפלתן של רבים שנאמר הן אל כביר ולא
>   ימאס

Soncino translation of the Gemoro:

> R. Nathan says: How do we know that the Holy One, blessed be He, does
>   not despise the prayer of the congregation? For it is said: ‘Behold,
>   God despiseth not the mighty’.

R Nathan understands “the mighty” to refer to the many who pray to Him.

It seems therefore that when we are requesting peace in Israel, we do need “the many”.

So it seems that it would be better to join in the Tehilim and requests for peace and finish off the other parts of davenning later.

Comment: I don't understand what the source has to do with the conclusion.

Comment: @Scimonster Tried to explain by translating the Gemoro. Does that help?

Comment: How does it follow that since "God doesn't despise the prayers of many" we need a minyan to daven for Israel?